# Does this freezing point depression problem make sense?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, phase

[image]

The solvent is water. Pure water has a freezing point of 0 degrees Celsius. How come, in this problem, the addition of solute results in an elevation of the freezing point from 0 to 0.46 degrees C? Is this possible? Or is this question just flawed?

Comment: If you'd see "Buffalo" written on an elephant's cage in a zoo, would you suspect a mistake, or suppose that you didn't know something?

Comment: I would assume that this is supposed to be $-0.46\ ^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$...

Comment: My thought as well.

Comment: Adding deuterium oxide would raise the freezing point.

Comment: I see no problem here. It's not a salt and it doesn't lower melting point but on contrary...

Comment: Truthfully it is very unlikely, but possible.

Comment: Ha, found it! http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57686/are-melting-points-for-mixtures-of-solids-always-below-the-melting-points-of-the

Comment: The solute does not need to be ionic but just be involatile relative to the solvent.